# How to get selected value from comboBox in phy using MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the selected value from my comboBox in PHP inside a while loop fetching MySQL results. How could I do it?

```
<?php
    include ("../conex.php");

    $conSql = ("CALL LISTAR_ASIGNATURAS()");
    $datos=mysqli_query($conex,$conSql);

    echo "<a style='font-size:16px;' href='../index.html'>Volver Atras</a>";
    echo " "; 
    echo "<select name='asigna' id='y' style='width:280px; height:23px;'>"; 
    echo "<option value='0'>Seleccione una Asignatura...</option>";

    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)) {   
        echo "<option value='".$fila["cod_asignatura"]."'>".$fila["nom_asignatura"]. "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo " ";

    echo "<input type='submit' onclick=location.href='listarasig2.php?codA=".$selected_val."' value='Buscar'>";
?>
```

Comment: what is the value of `$selected_val`?

Comment: none, was left there after many tries.

Comment: so basically you want to get the selected value of the combobox when you click the submit button?

Comment: Exactly. I need to store it so I can pass it down to my button.

Comment: then you need to put the combobox and the submit button inside the form tag.

Comment: I don't have a form tag.

Comment: or you could use jQuery to do that.

Comment: If you don't use jQuery and insist in using PHP alone, it will need to refresh the page to store the value of the combobox.

Comment: example on how to that in jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching data from MySQL database to html dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009464/fetching-data-from-mysql-database-to-html-dropdown-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this in jQuery.

```js
$('#testCombo').change(function() {
  var cboValue = this.value;
  var link;
  link = "location.href='listarasig2.php?codA=" + cboValue;
  $('#testSubmit').attr('onclick', link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="testCombo">
  <option value="0">test0</option>
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="testSubmit" />
```

or if you still want to use PHP, you could do something like this.

```js
echo "<a style='font-size:16px;' href='../index.html'>Volver Atras</a>";
echo " <form action='' method='get'>";
echo "<select name='asigna' id='y' style='width:280px; height:23px;'>";
echo "<option value='0'>Seleccione una Asignatura...</option>";
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)) {
  echo "<option value='".$fila["cod_asignatura"].
  "'>".$fila["nom_asignatura"].
  "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo " ";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Get Value'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "<input type='submit' onclick=location.href='listarasig2.php?codA=".$_GET['asigna'].
"' value='Buscar'>";
```