# Drop down list with data from database

Tags: php, html, sql, database, drop-down-menu

First of all I would like to let you know that I tried every other solution that I found here regarding to my topic.. But nothing worked for me!

As the title says I want to create a drop down list with data from a database!

The connection with the database is right so I don't show you the code! I have tried many ways, one is below.

The only thing that I am getting is a blank list.Thanks!

```
<select name="Anaktisi">
  <?php 

  $query2="select name from books WHERE sub_ID=1";
  $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);

  while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row2['name'];?>"> </option>
  <?php } ?>

</select>
```

Comment: `<option value="<?php echo $row2['name'];?>> </option>` is missing a closing " so it should be `<option value="<?php echo $row2['name'];?>"> </option>`

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [Fetching data from MySQL database to html dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009464/fetching-data-from-mysql-database-to-html-dropdown-list)

Comment: Try: `<option value="<?php echo $row2['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row2['name']; ?></option>`

Comment: @JustBaron  I tried what you said but i get the same blank thing!

Comment: @JSONGagnon you are right, but the result is the same..!

Comment: @Wondercricket I tried that way too, but i got no result.

Comment: @JustBaron has to correct syntax for displaying the name in the drop down itself and in the value. Try `<option value="<?php echo $row2['name'];?>"> (Some String) </option>` to see if it shows in the dropdown. If nothing shows after that, then there are probbaly no results being returned.

Comment: @JustBaron It shows nothing again! But I tried the query itself in the database and everything seems fine, it returns the correct results

Comment: Did you check if this condition is Ok? $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)

Comment: @RMH well how do i check that?

Comment: Your HTML contains the tag <option inside the tag <select name="Anaktisi">? Just to know if the result is passing inside the while. If not, we need to look some steps back!

Comment: @RMH after the <select name="Anaktisi"> the code is exactly how i write it above! So I think yes, the <option tag is inside the <select name="Anaktisi">

Comment: Yesman, but I'm asking after you run your application. Your code only produce the <option value if enter inside the while. If not enter in the while, your HTML will be just <select name="Anaktisi"></select>. Can u see the HTML after run the application?

Comment: @RMH actually i found the problem. the database connection was closing too early! Thank you! you helped me a lot :D

Comment: good job man!! That was my suspect!!! Your code was alright!